# Make threw out an error but no detailed error message

Tags: makefile

Here's the last few lines from the output of running "make install" at root level /home/gm/TEST/:

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gm/TEST/tppf/tm/ipmgt'
ld  ipfac.o ipfacV.o ipfac_rset.o ipfac_args.o ipfac_d2a.o ipfac_a2d.o ipfac_modr.o ipfac_mod.o ipfac_read.o ipfac_add.o ipfac_del.o ipfac_list.o ipfac_unlk.o ipfac_lock.o ipfac_util.o ipfac_lkid.o -r -o /home/gm/TEST/tppf/lib/ipfac_tppf.o
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gm/TEST/tppf/tm/ipfac'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gm/TEST/tppf/tm'
make[1]: *** [i_tm] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gm/TEST/tppf'
make: *** [i_tppf] Error 2
```

And the Makefile under /home/gm/TEST/tppf/tm/ipfac contains this rule:

```
install: ipfac.h $(TPPLIB)/ipfac_tppf.o

$(TPPLIB)/ipfac_tppf.o: $(PROPOBJS)
    ld  $(PROPOBJS) -r -o $(TPPLIB)/ipfac_tppf.o
```

Is there something wrong with the linking process? Make should've told me what the error actually is, but it didn't.

BTW, I think /home/gm/TEST/tppf/lib/ipfac_tppf. O was linked and created successfully, or at least it was there in directory /home/gm/TEST/tppf/lib/ after make failed and exited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That line is not the error line.  You can tell that it succeeded because there was no error message there, for building the target `/home/gm/TEST/tppf/lib/ipfac_tppf.o`.

The error is here:

```
make[1]: *** [i_tm] Error 2
```

The `[1]` means that it was the first level of makefile (note the recipe you are quoting here was in the 3rd level of makefile) and the `[i_tm]` means that the build of the target `i_tm` failed.  You need to look back up further in the output of make, earlier than what you've shown us, and find the `***` error line for building the `i_tm` target and see what errors were generated there.