# makefile - error 255 (recipe for target failed)

Tags: makefile

I'm reading ogldev tutorials for OpenGL4 (http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) and downloaded the source for all tutorials from the website. In the package there is a folder "Common" where you can find implementations for many ogldev functions and a makefile (probably for building a library?). It seems that building a lib from the source code found in Common folder is needed, as tutorials requires "Common.lib" to be included in the projects. So I tried to build the library using makefile found in Common folder. I opened cmd (I'm on Windows 7), navigated to the correct directory and run command "make", but it gave me "error 255":

```
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:90: recipe for target '.validate-impl' failed 
make: *** [.validate-impl] Error 255
```

I never used make before and I have no idea what the problem is. I tried googling it, but I haven't found anything useful for me.

Here's the code for Makefile-impl.mk:

```
#
# Generated - do not edit!
#
# NOCDDL
#
CND_BASEDIR=`pwd`
CND_BUILDDIR=build
CND_DISTDIR=dist
# Debug configuration
CND_PLATFORM_Debug=GNU-Linux-x86
CND_ARTIFACT_DIR_Debug=dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_Debug=libcommon.a
CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_Debug=dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/libcommon.a
CND_PACKAGE_DIR_Debug=dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/package
CND_PACKAGE_NAME_Debug=Common.tar
CND_PACKAGE_PATH_Debug=dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/package/Common.tar
# Release configuration
CND_PLATFORM_Release=GNU-Linux-x86
CND_ARTIFACT_DIR_Release=dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86
CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_Release=libcommon.a
CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_Release=dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/libcommon.a
CND_PACKAGE_DIR_Release=dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/package
CND_PACKAGE_NAME_Release=Common.tar
CND_PACKAGE_PATH_Release=dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/package/Common.tar
#
# include compiler specific variables
#
# dmake command
ROOT:sh = test -f nbproject/private/Makefile-variables.mk || \
    (mkdir -p nbproject/private && touch nbproject/private/Makefile-variables.mk)
#
# gmake command
.PHONY: $(shell test -f nbproject/private/Makefile-variables.mk || (mkdir -p nbproject/private && touch nbproject/private/Makefile-variables.mk))
#
include nbproject/private/Makefile-variables.mk
```

Comment: There must be a compiler/linker error there too.  That will be the root cause.

Comment: Hm, any further info what could I do with that?

Comment: We cannot help without knowing why `make` failed.

Comment: The point is that I also have no idea why this failed...

Comment: The build output will explain why it failed. If you don't understand the output you'd better post it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make threw out an error but no detailed error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690681/make-threw-out-an-error-but-no-detailed-error-message)