# Why does line 19 is giving error in this code?

Tags: linux, makefile

I have this code in maker file:

```
COMPILER = gcc
LINKER = ld
ASSEMBLER = nasm
CFLAGS = -m32 -c -ffreestanding
ASFLAGS = -f elf32
LDFLAGS = -m elf_i386 -T src/link.ld
EMULATOR = qemu-system-i386
EMULATOR_FLAGS = -kernel

OBJS = obj/kasm.o obj/kc.o obj/idt.o obj/isr.o obj/kb.o obj/screen.o obj/string.o obj/system.o obj/util.o obj/shell.o
OUTPUT = iknow/boot/kernel.bin

run: all
    $(EMULATOR) $(EMULATOR_FLAGS) $(OUTPUT)

all:$(OBJS)
    mkdir iknow/ -p
    mkdir iknow/boot/ -p
    $(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OBJS)

obj/kasm.o:src/kernel.asm
    $(ASSEMBLER) $(ASFLAGS) -o obj/kasm.o src/kernel.asm
    
obj/kc.o:src/kernel.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/kernel.c -o obj/kc.o 



    
obj/idt.o:src/idt.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/idt.c -o obj/idt.o 

obj/kb.o:src/kb.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/kb.c -o obj/kb.o

obj/isr.o:src/isr.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/isr.c -o obj/isr.o

obj/screen.o:src/screen.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/screen.c -o obj/screen.o

obj/string.o:src/string.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/string.c -o obj/string.o

obj/system.o:src/system.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/system.c -o obj/system.o

obj/util.o:src/util.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/util.c -o obj/util.o
    
obj/shell.o:src/shell.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) src/shell.c -o obj/shell.o

build:all
    #Activate the install xorr if you do not have it already installed
    #sudo apt-get install xorriso
    rm iknow/boot/grub/ -r -f
    mkdir iknow/boot/grub/
    echo set default=0 >> iknow/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo set timeout=0 >> iknow/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo menuentry "IKnow" { >> iknow/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo         set root='(hd96)' >> iknow/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo         multiboot /boot/kernel.bin >> iknow/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo } >> iknow/boot/grub/grub.cfg

    grub-mkrescue -o iknow.iso iknow/
    
clear:
    rm -f obj/*.o
    rm -r -f iknow/
```

and after running it with all permission and root previliges it generates this error

```
make: *** [makefile:19: all] Error 1
```

I cannot see any error in line 19 in the code I tried to search on internet and found nothing about this error.

I tried to resolve the error using this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300661/make-makefile-install-ucb13-install-dat-error-1
but nothing worked out

Comment: Is it all it outputs?

Comment: `make: *** [makefile:19: all] Error 1 ` Typically, this is an error from one of the commands being run, and that command will print out an error message. Are there any error messages above this line?

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you marked line 19 so we would know it without having to count.  But, that message doesn't mean your makefile is wrong.  if it were wrong, make would tell you what's wrong.  That error means that the command make invoked, which is at line 19 of the makefile, failed.  make has no idea how or why it failed.  So you have to look at the output of the command and fix whatever errors it printed, so it's not failing anymore.

Comment: Maybe a tabs vs space issue? Makefile syntax is a bit picky in this respect.

Comment: @janneb No.  That would give a much different error.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690681/make-threw-out-an-error-but-no-detailed-error-message

Answer (score 0):

You may know this already, but the line that seems to be failing is the `$(LINKER)` line.  It appears that `ld` is returning -1.  usually, this due to a prior compiler error.  Were all `.o`'s compiled successfully?